# linux: passing arguments to the .bashrc file

Tags: linux, bash

I want to be able to run bash in different predefined configurations. for example: When i'm at work i'll do something like:

```
bash work
```

And it will load the appropriate environment variables.

The way i see it, the best way of doing it is passing the configuration name to the .bashrc command and than just configure it according to the name.

To do that, i need to pass the name to the .bashrc file.. How do i pass arguments to the .bashrc file from the bash command?

Of course alternatives for doing what i want will be appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the man page:

```
--rcfile file
Execute commands from file instead of the standard personal initialization file ~/.bashrc if the shell is interactive (see INVOCATION below).
```

I don't think you can pass arguments to your individual bashrc directly, but you can call a common bashrc from your customized rc files and then either use arguments or global variables.

If you just want to set some environment variables, you can of course just manually call your customised rc file. To make this a little nicer from your command line, you can define a respective alias:

```
alias load_work='~/.workrc'
```

or with a new bash

```
alias load_work='bash --rcfile ~/.workrc'
```

Comment: The first alias requires the script be executable and neither will run them in the current shell session (so they won't change anything). You want `source` or `.` instead of `bash`.

Comment: Thank you both! the --rcfile option suits my needs.